# adverbial phrase- two Tuesdays ago?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

What does "two Tuesdays ago" mean in the following?

John met Bill two Tuesdays ago.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

John met Bill not last Tuesday, but the Tuesday before.